# One type argument expected for class DrawerItem

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a `JAVA` class:

```
public abstract class DrawerItem<T extends DrawerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    protected boolean isChecked;
    public abstract T createViewHolder(ViewGroup parent);
    public abstract void bindViewHolder(T holder);

    public DrawerItem<T>setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked();
    }

    public boolean isSelectable(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

From a `KOTLIN` file I call it like this:

```
private fun createItemFor(position :Int): DrawerItem {
    return SimpleItem(screenIcons[position], screenTitles[position])
        .withIconTint(R.color.bottom_menu_unselected)
        .withTextTint(R.color.black)
        .withSelectedIconTint(R.color.bottom_menu_unselected)
        .withSelectedTextTint(R.color.bottom_menu_unselected)
}
```

I get an error: `One type argument expected for class DrawerItem<T : DrawerAdapter.ViewHolder!>`

What am I missing? I am not sure what I should specify in order for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DrawerItem has a type, and Kotlin does not allow raw types. In most places where you could use a raw type in Java, you can use star projection in Kotlin, like this:

```
private fun createItemFor(position :Int): DrawerItem<*> { //...
```

If you need to use it in a way where you need to know the type of the ViewHolder returned by `SimpleItem.createViewHolder()`, you either need to specify the type specifically (whatever the type is that SimpleItem uses), or you can use `=` to allow the return type to be implicitly specified so you don't have to think about it:

```
private fun createItemFor(position :Int) =
    SimpleItem(screenIcons[position], screenTitles[position])
        .withIconTint(R.color.bottom_menu_unselected)
        .withTextTint(R.color.black)
        .withSelectedIconTint(R.color.bottom_menu_unselected)
        .withSelectedTextTint(R.color.bottom_menu_unselected)
```